Having issue with calculating SINR using TensorFlow, how numerically stable is TF when it comes to complex numbers?
I have code for training a neural network and the loss is negative SINR, for a system with multi group (G) and multi users (K). However when I calculate the sinr, something odd happens.
the SINR formula is this:

And this is my code:
def find_sinr_over_group(H, W):

    sigma2 = 1
    # Compute the Hermitian transpose (conjugate transpose) of W
    W_H = tf.transpose(tf.math.conj(W), perm=[0, 2, 1])  # Shape: (batch_size, G, M)

    # Compute Signal Power for each user in each group
    signal_power = []
    for g in range(W.shape[-1]):  # Loop over each group g
        w_h_g = W_H[:, g, :]  # Shape: (batch_size, M)
        h_g = H[:, :, :, g]  # Shape: (batch_size, M, K)

        # Matrix multiplication to compute signal power
        s = tf.matmul(w_h_g[:, tf.newaxis, :], h_g)  # Shape: (batch_size, 1, K)
        s = tf.squeeze(s, axis=1)  # Shape: (batch_size, K)
        signal_power.append(s)

    signal_power = tf.stack(signal_power, axis=-1)  # Shape: (batch_size, K, G)
    signal_power = tf.math.real(tf.math.multiply(signal_power, tf.math.conj(signal_power)))
    # signal_power = tf.math.abs(signal_power) ** 2  # Take the absolute square

    # Compute Total Power for each user in each group
    total_power = []
    for g in range(W.shape[-1]):  # Loop over each group g
        w_h = W_H[:, :, :]  # Shape: (batch_size, G, M)
        h_g = H[:, :, :, g]  # Shape: (batch_size, M, K)

        # Matrix multiplication to compute total power
        t = tf.matmul(w_h, h_g)  # Shape: (batch_size, G, K)
        t = tf.math.real(tf.math.multiply(t, tf.math.conj(t)))
        # t = tf.math.abs(t) ** 2  # Shape: (batch_size, G, K)
        total_power.append(tf.reduce_sum(t, axis=1))  # Sum across G to get (batch_size, K)

    total_power = tf.stack(total_power, axis=-1)  # Shape: (batch_size, K, G)

    # Isolate the Interference Power by subtracting Signal Power from Total Power
    interference_power = total_power - signal_power  # Shape: (batch_size, K, G)

    # Add noise power
    interference_plus_noise_power = interference_power + sigma2  # Add noise

    # Compute SINR
    sinr = signal_power / interference_plus_noise_power  # Shape: (batch_size, K, G)

    return sinr

But the problem is, the interference power in some cases is negative. Which numerically impossible since the signal power is just a special case of the total power. Anyone knows why this happens and how should I fix it?
As you can see, at first i used the tf.abd function and then raise by the power of 2. I thought that might be an issue with abs so I tried myltipying by conjugate to get the power of the signal. But still I have this issue.

Are you taking into account i≠j from formula (maybe I just can't see it)? Second thing, analyse simple cases and check if they work, if not it will be easier to understand what's going on. Last but not least, create minimal, reproducible example - it's hard to analyse your code as is, with some example it would be easier to help you
